# Reference cell in as sheetname

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
'SHEET_NAME'!A:A
```

but how would I reference `B3` where it says `SHEET_NAME`? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & B3 & "'!A:A")
```

Just realize that INDIRECT is volatile, in that it will force the formula to re-calc every time Excel does a calculation, even if the underlying data has not changed.  Too many of these and you will start to notice a lag in the calc times.

Comment: is there a way to fix the punctuation so `INDIRECT()` will recognize `'` and `&` instead of saying `#REF!`

Comment: @Bradon Not sure I understand?  You only get `#REF` if you delete the cell to which the formula is pointing.

Comment: I have 4. 1 has just the 1 `'` and 3 of them have both a `' ` and a `&` in them. Upon a closer look, i think it's the `'` i have others with the '&' and they work fine.

Comment: have to use `INDIRECT("'"&SUBSTITUTE(B16," ' "," ' ' ")&"'!A:A")`